# hide @property in objective C

Tags: objective-c

How to hide @property(retain, nonatomic)NSString*str in some class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a feature called “categories,” which allows you to extend an existing class by adding properties and methods to it.

Typically, you use an empty category inside your class's .m file for private methods and properties, and define a separate named category in an external .h file for protected members. Categories are actually quite interesting in that they allow you to *override* existing properties. So, for example, you can define a property as read-only in your .h file:

```
@interface Whatever {
    NSObject *aValue;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain,readonly) NSObject *aValue;

@end
```

And then you can make it read/write for your own private use in an empty category inside your .m file:

```
@interface Whatever()
  @property (nonatomic,retain) NSObject *aValue;
@end
```

You can find more about categories [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1).

Comment: That isn't a category; that is a class extension.  Class extensions and categories are similar, but extensions have subtle, but significant (and by design), differences in use than categories when it comes to @property.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to hide it from being visible in the .h file, consider using a private class extension in the .m file:

```
@interface YourClass ()

@property(retain, nonatomic)NSString*str;

@end
```